# Making the axis bigger or autoadjust to allow more ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to that the figure in matplotlib can auto adjust the axis to accomodate more ticks

```
    ticks = [0.5, 5.5, 10.5, 15.5, 20.5, 25.5, 29.5, 31.5, 36.5, 41.5, 46.5, 51.5, 56.5, 60, 65, 70]
    labels = ["0", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "29", "0", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "60", "65", "70"]
    axes.set_xticks(ticks)
    axes.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

The above code only show the ticks up to 60.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the problem is with the automatic limits, so try:

```
axes.set_xlim(0, 70)
```